# AWS Cloudformation Userdata powershell script not running on custom Windows Server AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cloudformation

I have tried all troubleshooting in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158411/amazon-ec2-custom-ami-not-running-bootstrap-user-data) to no avail.

```
"UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "<powershell>\n",
                                "New-Item C:\\Temp\\test.txt -ItemType file \n",
                                "</powershell>\n",
                                "<persist>true</persist>"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

test.txt file doesnt get created in the C:\Temp folder.

> C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log:

```
2018/01/19 02:26:55Z: Userdata execution begins
2018/01/19 02:26:55Z: Zero or more than one <persist> tag was not provided
2018/01/19 02:26:55Z: Unregistering the persist scheduled task
2018/01/19 02:27:18Z: Zero or more than one <runAsLocalSystem> tag was not provided
2018/01/19 02:27:18Z: Zero or more than one <script> tag was not provided
2018/01/19 02:27:19Z: Zero or more than one <powershellArguments> tag was not provided
2018/01/19 02:27:19Z: <powershell> tag was provided.. running powershell content
2018/01/19 07:49:57Z: Userdata execution begins
2018/01/19 07:49:57Z: Failed to get metadata: The result from http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data was empty
2018/01/19 07:50:00Z: Unable to execute userdata: Userdata was not provided
2018/01/19 07:50:00Z: Userdata execution done
```

But i can see the script at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`

```
<powershell>
New-Item C:\Temp\test.txt -ItemType file 
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

Answer (score 0):

> > TLDR; By running SysPrep on the instance used to create the custom AMI, my userdata scripts are now executing on first launch by
> >     Cloudformation.
>
> Running Sysprep using the EC2Launch Settings Application:
>
> > 1. In the Amazon EC2 console, locate or create a Windows Server 2016 AMI.
> > 2. Launch a Windows instance from the AMI.
> > 3. Connect to your Windows instance and customize it.
> > 4. Search for and run the EC2LaunchSettings application. It is located in the following 
> >        directory by default: `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Settings`.
> > 5. Select or clear options as needed. These settings are stored in the LaunchConfig.json 
> >        file. 
> >        6.Choose Shutdown with Sysprep.
>
> After Sysprep has been configured for the Windows Server 2016
>   custom image the AMI can be safely created. Adding the newly created
>   AMI to the CFN template the execution results in a success.
>
> References:
>
> > 1. [Microsoft System Preparation Tool configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html#ec2launch-sysprep)
> > 2. [More information on SysPrep](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ami-create-standard.html#sysprep-begin)

Answer (score 0):

For the custom AMI's user data are already disabled to enable it run following command in powershell.

C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 –Schedule

And then the userdata script should work.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command and take the AMI

```
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1 –Schedule
```