# Automate powershell script when system boots

Tags: powershell, window

I have the following powershell script:

```
(Get-Content C:/sample.txt -TotalCount 1) | Set-Content C:\sample.txt
```

I would like the above script to execute when system boot.

Can someone please advise the best option to do so?
Thank you
Manu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run PowerShell Script when computer starts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-to-run-powershell-script-when-computer-starts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a scheduled task and configure it to run the script when the server boots.
Every time server starts, it will start the script.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to solve the situation:
-create a .cmd file to execute automatically your script at system boot, with following script:
PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" | powershell.exe -noexit C:\cldscripts\sample.ps1

Copy and save your .cmd file in the following path:
C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
Reboot your system and the scrip will automatically run.

Another way I found, is to use the grouop local editor:
Run the gpedit.msc and enter.
In the left pane tree choose windows settings under Computer configuration, double click on the feature "Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)" and add your script to run automatically at system boot or shutdown.

Best Regards

Comment: As @23Stinger noted, a script run from the `Start Menu\Programs\Startup` directory is a login script, not a startup script.  The script will not run until that user logs in, and it will execute under that user's account.  Also, it is possible (if not preferable) to invoke a PowerShell script without permanently changing the machine execution policy using the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit C:\cldscripts\sample.ps1`.  That PowerShell session will run with the specified execution policy but the system execution policy will remain unchanged.