# How to start a PS script file with a batch/cmd?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a Power Shell script file (it's PS5 on Win10) that allow me to change to a specific wallpaper when I execute it. I can only do that if I have administrator access. 
There are ways work around like making a .bat file

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -file "C:\Users\name\wallp1.ps1"
```

But it seems that method will change execution policy permanently to unrestricted which is really unsecure
What I want is to be able to execute a PS script through Task Scheduler (it must be through that not through Startup folder). I want to be able to change Wallpaper on a specific time and only Task Scheduler can do that. Unless I can do that with command or batch files.

In short: I want to run a PS script through another file without messing with current Execution Policy

Other method seems not work: [how to run PowerShell Script when computer starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-to-run-powershell-script-when-computer-starts)

Or maybe there is a way to be able to revert back to default execution policy after the PS script has ran? It must be done automatically in one file

Comment: Hi, _But it seems that method will change execution policy permanently to unrestricted_ I don't believe so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the launch command you provided does **not** change the execution policy permanently on the host. Tested on Win10 with PS5.

[Second most upvoted `powershell` question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: but every time I open up PowerShell both regular and as admin and type get-executionploicy -list it always lists as unrestricted

Comment: Well, your command temporarily sets it to `Bypass`. Try permanently setting it to `RemoteSigned`, for instance (as admin), and then use your shortcut again.

Comment: I thought Remote signed only allow scripts that are signed to execute?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems there was something wrong with my laptop. Desktop returned RemoteSigned as usual