# How to run powershell script on computer start-up

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to run a PowerShell script `Daily.ps1` on start-up, however, due to administrator settings (I cannot run as admin, that is not an option), I cannot run it through the Task Scheduler. For example, this is the contents of `Daily.ps1`:

```
if (1 -eq 1) {
    "Hello there!"
}
```

1. So I tried to have a batch script `Daily.cmd` run on start up (through the start-up folder), which runs, but I cannot get it run the `Daily.ps1`, and I get a message saying running scripts is disabled. (Both files are in the same directory)

   ```
   powershell C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Daily.ps1
   ```

   > File C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Daily.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system
2. I then tried using this line of code from a trick I learned to bypass running scripts directly:

   ```
   powershell cat Daily.ps1 | powershell invoke-expression
   ```

   This works but only for one liners.  So I added the `-raw` flag for 
   `cat`, which works when in powershell, but not in CMD.  For some reason, `Daily.ps1`'s text is still stored as an array of strings. (apologies for formatting)

   > cmdlet Invoke-Expression at command pipeline position 1
   >
   > > Supply values for the following parameters:
   > >
   > > > Command: if (1 -eq 1) {
   > > >
   > > > - invoke-expression : At line:1 char:14
   > > > - if (1 -eq 1) {
   > > > - Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
   > > > - At line:1 char:1
   > > > - invoke-expression                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3. So I tried to add this to `Daily.cmd`:

   ```
   powershell
   cat -raw Daily.ps1 | powershell-invoke-expression
   ```

   However, the rest of the script doesn't get executed at all once I enter PowerShell.

I don't know to get `Daily.ps1` to run through a batch command.  Is there a way I missed, or is one of the ways I tried faulty (without admin rights)?

Edit:  To clarify, `ExecutionPolicy` is set to `Restricted`, and that cannot be changed.  Additionally, I can run PowerShell scripts fine through right clicking the file and running with PS.

Comment: Additionally, I cannot download any software.  If I can do this strictly through batch or PowerShell, that would be preferable

Comment: It may just be that your execution policy has not been set from the default `Restricted`. Try to invoke powershell.exe with command line options, possibly like this: `PowerShell -File "C:\Users\sixu\Desktop\Daily.ps1" -NoProfile -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: I cannot run the script regardless since the `ExecutionPolicy` is set to `Restricted` and I cannot change that.

Comment: there are apparently ways to _totally block_ running PoSh. i think `applocker` is one such. you likely need to talk to your net/sys admin about this.

Comment: Did you use the command line I have provided? or is that simply a reactive response? We cannot know if ideas work if you do not try them!

Comment: Yes, I did try it.  I just added an edit to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask somebody else to say hello to you every day instead :-)

Comment: This could be helpful: [How do I run a PowerShell script when the computer starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-do-i-run-a-powershell-script-when-the-computer-starts) or this: [How can a PowerShell script be automatically run on startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/688007/how-can-a-powershell-script-be-automatically-run-on-startup)

Comment: I tried both those options, however, the problem is that I cannot change the `ExecutionProperty` to anything other than `restricted`.  Which seems to be the root of this issue.  Given my circumstances, that property must stay `restricted`. 
 But for some reason, I am still able to run `.ps1` files through right clicking and "run with powershell".  I expected there to be a way to execute any GUI actions through the command line, but maybe that is not the case for PowerShell Scripts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer!

After trying many different methods, I came across this line of code that allows you to run PS scripts if `ExecutionProperty` is set to `restricted`:

```
start powershell "cat -raw C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Daily.ps1 | invoke-expression"
```

This runs powershell and uses the trick of piping the results of `cat -raw [file.ps1]` to `invoke-expression`.  This is useful workaround if `ExecutionProperty` is set to `restricted`.

Then you can save this line to a `.cmd` or `.bat` file and use either Task Scheduler (more customizability) or put it in the startup folder.

P.S. for everyone who kept saying change the `ExecutionProperty` to something other than  `restricted`.  I clearly stated multiple times that I cannot do that(not admin), nor will the Sys Admin do that, nor will it ever happen(must stay `restricted`) :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task to run at computer startup. Put `powershell.exe` in the field "program/script" and `-File "C:\path\to\your.ps1"` in the field "arguments" (you may want to avoid placing the script in a user profile). Set the task to run whether the user is logged on or not.

Comment: I hate repeating myself, but all these methods do not work be cause they assume I can run PS scripts through the command line normally.  All these methods require `ExecutionProperty` to be set to something other than `restricted`, which cannot happem, the property must stay `restricted`.  However, I can run the PS script normally through the windows interface, by rightclicking the file and running with PS.  Thus I assumed there must be a way to execute any UI commands through the command line.  Perhaps that is a poor assumption, but one would think the command line were more powerful.

Comment: @Simon Then change the execution policy to something sensible like "RemoteSigned", or add `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the arguments. If you can do neither then the execution policy is most likely administratively set through a group policy, in which case you should talk to your IT department. Otherwise you might be violating company policies.