# How to run a powershell script on boot/login using only powershell

Tags: powershell

I've tried the answers that were posted here: [How do I run a PowerShell script when the computer starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-do-i-run-a-powershell-script-when-the-computer-starts#)

Tried the 50 upvote solution and it did not work, so I'm looking at other alternatives. Whatever solution there is *has* to be able to be completed using only powershell commands.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is considered a little vague on stackoverflow. Please specify what goes wrong and add as many details as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Could you not just create a registry value to do run it at startup?  Open Regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Create a new String value - name it whatever you want.  And for the data, provide the command that you want to run (Powershell.exe command line)?  For example:

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Name: MyPowerShellScript
Data: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Path\To\File.ps1"
```

Comment: "Whatever solution there is has to be able to be completed using only powershell commands."  regedit is a gui tool

Comment: Then write the registry entry using PowerShell!!?  If you want a clear answer, you need to write a clear question.  It's vague.  There is no explanation of what you have specifically tried.  And there is no reason given as to why you can only use PowerShell.