# DisableAbsoluteVolume on Windows 10

Tags: wpf, bluetooth, windows-10, user32, systemparametersinfo

There are some settings that I need to be able to set at runtime, without a reboot.  Using [X-Mouse Controls](https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/) as a guide, I've found a way to programmatically use `SystemParametersInfo()` to set up active window tracking (`SPI_SET_ACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING`), not raising windows on focus (`SPI_SET_ACTIVEWNDTRKZORDER`), and the active window tracking timeout (`SPI_ACTIVEWNDTRKTIMEOUT`).

All three of these settings are available through registry keys, but altering the values in the registry would necessitate a reboot.  Using the `SystemParamtersInfo()` call on the other hand, obviates this reboot.

Here's an example of one of the calls:

```
public static void SetActiveWindowTracking(bool enabled)
{
    bool result = NativeMethods.SystemParametersInfo((uint) SPI.SPI_SETACTIVEWINDOWTRACKING, UiParamNoOp, enabled.AsUIntPtr(), SpifWrite);

    if (!result)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
```

The next setting I want to tackle is disabling Bluetooth absolute volume.  This setting is available in the registry, at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT`.  However, if I simply alter this value, I will have to reboot to enable my new setting.  I am interested in altering this setting without rebooting, similar to the three settings above.  Is there a function I can call, either `SystemParametersInfo()`, or something similar, which will give me the capability of twiddling this setting without a reboot?

BTW, I'm working in C♯ with WPF.  I am, however, open to other solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a good answer for the problem but I have a direction that worth trying I hope. One simple approach would  be to try to update the registry for DisableAbsoluteVolume with value 1 and than to use this script from Url (https://superuser.com/questions/1168551/turn-on-off-bluetooth-radio-adapter-from-cmd-powershell-in-windows-10) that will turn on/off the Bluetooth and hopefully it will retake the values from registry. If not, you can procced further based on this script and investigate deeper if you can use WinRT API to trigger the wanted functionality.

Comment: @DA Intriguing.  The only downside I see to this involves playback being killed if something is going while the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Windows Audio Core lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/programming-guide?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for options and I added 3 ways to do it.

Just execute this as a batch file/CMD at [Startup](https://jd-bots.com/2021/05/15/how-to-run-powershell-script-on-windows-startup/) or [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-do-i-run-a-powershell-script-when-the-computer-starts/41406026)

> ### - Option 1: Via `registry` update  / `powershell`, needs *reboot*

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT /v DisableAbsoluteVolume /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---

> ### - Option 2: Via code `PInvoke`

```
// Declare your PInvoke
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
// Now call it
 SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle, (IntPtr) APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
```

---

> ### - Option 3: Without `interop` and no 3rd party libs, just windows audio core lib credit simon from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322736/6085193)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SetAppVolumne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string app = "Mozilla Firefox";

            foreach (string name in EnumerateApplications())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("name:" + name);
                if (name == app)
                {
                    // display mute state & volume level (% of master)
                    Console.WriteLine("Mute:" + GetApplicationMute(app));
                    Console.WriteLine("Volume:" + GetApplicationVolume(app));

                    // mute the application
                    SetApplicationMute(app, true);

                    // set the volume to half of master volume (50%)
                    SetApplicationVolume(app, 50);
                }
            }
        }

        public static float? GetApplicationVolume(string name)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return null;

            float level;
            volume.GetMasterVolume(out level);
            return level * 100;
        }

        public static bool? GetApplicationMute(string name)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return null;

            bool mute;
            volume.GetMute(out mute);
            return mute;
        }

        public static void SetApplicationVolume(string name, float level)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return;

            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            volume.SetMasterVolume(level / 100, ref guid);
        }

        public static void SetApplicationMute(string name, bool mute)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return;

            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            volume.SetMute(mute, ref guid);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateApplications()
        {
            // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
            IMMDevice speakers;
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
            Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
            object o;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
            IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

            // enumerate sessions for on this device
            IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
            mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
            int count;
            sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                IAudioSessionControl ctl;
                sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);
                string dn;
                ctl.GetDisplayName(out dn);
                yield return dn;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
        }

        private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(string name)
        {
            // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
            IMMDevice speakers;
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
            Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
            object o;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
            IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

            // enumerate sessions for on this device
            IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
            mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
            int count;
            sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

            // search for an audio session with the required name
            // NOTE: we could also use the process id instead of the app name (with IAudioSessionControl2)
            ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                IAudioSessionControl ctl;
                sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);
                string dn;
                ctl.GetDisplayName(out dn);
                if (string.Compare(name, dn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
                    break;
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
            return volumeControl;
        }
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
    internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
    {
    }

    internal enum EDataFlow
    {
        eRender,
        eCapture,
        eAll,
        EDataFlow_enum_count
    }

    internal enum ERole
    {
        eConsole,
        eMultimedia,
        eCommunications,
        ERole_enum_count
    }

    [Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDevice
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppInterface);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionManager2
    {
        int NotImpl1();
        int NotImpl2();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionEnumerator(out IAudioSessionEnumerator SessionEnum);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("E2F5BB11-0570-40CA-ACDD-3AA01277DEE8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionEnumerator
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetCount(out int SessionCount);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSession(int SessionCount, out IAudioSessionControl Session);
    }

    [Guid("F4B1A599-7266-4319-A8CA-E70ACB11E8CD"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionControl
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface ISimpleAudioVolume
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMasterVolume(float fLevel, ref Guid EventContext);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMasterVolume(out float pfLevel);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMute(bool bMute, ref Guid EventContext);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMute(out bool pbMute);
    }
}
```

Comment: That still requires a reboot.  I need something to set it up on the fly.  Just running that command updates the registry, but the change doesn't occur until after reboot.