# Run python code from powershell script as Windows Service at Startup

Tags: python, windows, powershell, service

I would like to run a python script everytime the computer boots, without having to login.

To do so, I tried to create a windows service that will first run a powershell script (to do some basic check configurations) and that will run a simple python command line like this:

```
python ./app.py
```

But like I said I would like this script to run at startup and for this I've created a windows service. The problem is that even though the powershell script runs, the python command (and only this command) **won't work**.

### Some usefull information

If I start the powershell script from a terminal: **it works.**

If I start the python script directly from a terminal: **it works.**

If I start the python script as a background process with `pythonw`: **it works.**

I know the powershell scripts runs at startup because I asked him to create folders (as a test) to show me **it works.**

The python program is using multi threading and a network connection. I don't know if that's relevant but that just to say it's a pretty big program that doesn't need any human interaction and that works on its own. Maybe Windows is blocking something about that ?

Other information: the powershell script (and so the python script) both need to run as Administrator. I know it already does because with the following condition it creates a folder.

```
if (([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
    mkdir C:\Users\Desktop\Test2
}
```

### What I've tried

I first created a windows service in **C#** that runs with full privileges with this basic code:

```
var ps1File = @"C:\\path\\to\\powershell\\script\\start.ps1";

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-NoProfile -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\"",
                UseShellExecute = true
            };
            Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The service does seem to works like I said, it really is the python command that won't.

I also tried to create a service with **NSSM** and with **AlwaysUp** too but nothing works.

Comment: The usual suspects are the _user privileges_ (because the service may run under a different account than yours) and the _environment_. You can use your C# service to print out PATH, PYTHONPATH, etc in the service context and compare to your own context.

Comment: @joao Thanks for your answer. You made me realize that PYthon wasn't installed on the system but only for my local account. It would have been a problem at a certain point so thanks.
But unfortunately the service still won't run, I'll look more into the user privileges but if you have anywhere else to look, please be my guest

Comment: In the past if you wanted a service to run a command line program like the Python interpreter then it needed the special privilege *Interact with desktop*. But that privilege is now viewed as a security risk and has been largely nerfed. You can write a service directly in Python as explained in Hammond & Robinson, *Python Programming on Win32*, O'Reilly, ISBN 978-156592621-9 (https://zulfahmed.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/markhammond-andyrobinson-pythonwin32.pdf) Chapter 18. That book was written for Python 2 but AFAIK it is still the best resource and covers all the plumbing needed.

Comment: If it just needs to run once at startup instead of run constantly in the background, I recommend adding your script to your startup programs instead of creating a service for it. There are some oddities, but either this answer or the one below it about a simple task scheduler entry will have what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189430/7411885