# Run nextjs application in the background

Tags: node.js, windows, next.js, pm2

I have an application built with nextJs and this application should work on a local server (**Windows**).
my customer told me that he needed this application to work in the background after searching I found that I needed to use a package called `pm2` and when I used it gives me an error and I found that I needed to make some configurations for it and I can't found any helping resources, please help

Comment: What do you mean by running in the background?

Comment: the application run automatically when the server boot or reboot and not using cmd to run it

Comment: You might want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-do-i-run-a-powershell-script-when-the-computer-starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that to run nextJs application in the background you will need a custom configuration

1. you need to download the pm2 globally in your system
2. create a file with the name `ecosystem.config.js` in the root folder next to the `package.json` file
3. you need to put your config data in this file which would be something like this

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: "inventory_test",
            script: "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
            args: "start -p 3333", //running on port 3000
            watch: false,
        },
    ],
};
```

- you should set the `name` as the name you want to see when you check
  the list of `pm2`
- the problem will be solved when you set the `script` as I did in the code above to be more precise the default run of `pm2` is to go to the node js folder in the system and try to make `start` for the application using npm directly but this is the problem we need to make it use the node runner from the nextjs itself or something like this so we change the script as above
- after that, we set the `arguments` that we should run after the `npm` and in my example is the arg `start` and choose the port for our application too

and now we make our config

**NOTES**

1. you should make `build` before you start the application
2. to run the project you will open the folder of the project in the `terminal` || `cmd` || `cmder` and run the command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`